# What is the grid_size parameter in shapely operations do?

Tags: python, shapely

In a practical sense, what does the `grid_size` parameter do for you?  When/why would you change it from the default?

I understand from testing that it imposes a discretization on the coordinates of the resulting geometries, e.g. with `grid_size=0.01` the fractional part of the coordinates will be multiples of `0.01`.  Does this play into the logic of the algorithms or is just a convenience for applications where, in the end, the user is going to discretize the coordinates anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A practical reason why I use it sometimes is to avoid having slivers after applying overlays (in non-topological data).

The code sample below illustrates this:

- the intersection between the 2 polygons without grid_size results in
  a narrow polygon as intersection.
- the intersection between the 2 polygons with grid_size results in a
  line, which is easy to filter out.

```
import shapely
import shapely.plotting
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

poly1 = shapely.Polygon([(0, 0), (0, 10), (10, 10), (5, 0), (0, 0)])
poly2 = shapely.Polygon([(5, 0), (8, 7), (10, 7), (10, 0), (5, 0)])

intersection_nogridsize = poly1.intersection(poly2)
intersection_gridsize = poly1.intersection(poly2, grid_size=1)

shapely.plotting.plot_polygon(poly1, color="green")
shapely.plotting.plot_polygon(poly2, color="blue")
shapely.plotting.plot_polygon(intersection_nogridsize, color="red")
plt.show()

shapely.plotting.plot_polygon(poly1, color="green")
shapely.plotting.plot_polygon(poly2, color="blue")
shapely.plotting.plot_line(intersection_gridsize, color="red")
plt.show()
```

Result without gridsize (red intersection is a polygon):

[image: result without gridsize]

Result with gridsize (red intersection is a line):

[image: result with gridsize]

Comment: Is there documentation on the algorithm that is used by shapely?  Other than the coordinates being on a grid I'm unclear why/how one results in a polygon and the other in a line geometry.

Comment: Shapely is mainly a python wrapper around [GEOS](https://www.libgeos.org), a c++ library, and that's a port of [JTS](https://locationtech.github.io/jts). So, for implementation details, those are the places to be. One of the developers also has some blog posts that might interest you, [here](http://lin-ear-th-inking.blogspot.com/2020/05/jts-overlay-next-generation.html)

Comment: Regarding the polygon becoming a line due to the grid size. To my understanding, when specifying the grid size, you are specifying how precise you want the output to be. The most obvious result of this is that the coordinates are rounded, but this also implies that eg. polygons narrower than this precision are snapped together... to lines. So in the above example, the resulting polygon is narrower than 1... so it is snapped together to a line.